# Most efficient way to pivot multiple groups over multiple columns using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Can anyone help identify the most efficient way to pivot data in multiple groups, over multiple columns, using Oracle SQL?

I have a table as follows:

```
NAME    MEAL    FOOD    DRINK
Dan     Lunch   Taco    Coke
Dan     Dinner  Steak   Water
Becky   Lunch   Pizza   Coke
Becky   Dinner  Pizza   Milk
```

And my desired output is a table as follows:

```
NAME    LUNCH_FOOD    LUNCH_DRINK    DINNER_FOOD    DINNER_DRINK
Dan     Taco          Coke           Steak          Water
Becky   Pizza         Coke           Pizza          Milk
```

What is the best way to go about doing this? My solution below accomplishes the task, but I have a feeling there is a more efficient approach:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (PERSON VARCHAR(10), MEAL VARCHAR(10), FOOD VARCHAR(10), DRINK VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (PERSON, MEAL, FOOD, DRINK) VALUES ('Dan', 'Lunch', 'Taco', 'Coke');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (PERSON, MEAL, FOOD, DRINK) VALUES ('Dan', 'Dinner', 'Steak', 'Water');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (PERSON, MEAL, FOOD, DRINK) VALUES ('Becky', 'Lunch', 'Pizza', 'Coke');
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (PERSON, MEAL, FOOD, DRINK) VALUES ('Becky', 'Dinner', 'Pizza', 'Milk');
```

Current Solution:

```
SELECT t1."PERSON",
       t1."FOOD" AS "LUNCH_FOOD",
       t1."DRINK" AS "LUNCH_DRINK",
       t2."FOOD" AS "DINNER_FOOD",
       t2."DRINK" AS "DINNER_DRINK"
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM EXAMPLE
         WHERE "MEAL" = 'Lunch') t1
       FULL JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM EXAMPLE
                   WHERE "MEAL" = 'Dinner') t2
          ON t1."PERSON" = t2."PERSON";
```

Edit: Should note that I'm using a full join here because there are instances in the actual use case in which one person might be in one group but not the other (i.e. someone might have a lunch entry but no corresponding dinner entry). Also, can assume that each person only has 1 lunch and 1 dinner row, never more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when meal = 'Lunch' then food end) as lunch_food,
       max(case when meal = 'Lunch' then drink end) as lunch_drink,
       max(case when meal = 'Dinner' then food end) as dinner_food,
       max(case when meal = 'Dinner' then drink end) as dinner_drink
from example
group by name;
```

However, if you have a large table, you might compare that to:

```
select name, l.food, l.drink, d.food, d.drink
from (select e.*
      from example e 
      where meal = 'Lunch'
     ) l full join
     (select e.*
      from dinner e 
      where meal = 'Dinner'
     ) d
     using (name);
```

Oracle has efficient mechanisms for aggregation.  It is hard to say off-hand which will be faster, so you should try on your data.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select *
from example
pivot (
max(FOOD) as FOOD,max(DRINK) as DRINK
for MEAL in ('Lunch' as Lunch,'Dinner' as Dinner)
);
```

Results:

```
PERSON     LUNCH_FOOD LUNCH_DRINK  DINNER_FOOD  DINNER_DRINK
---------- ---------- ------------ ------------ ------------
Becky      Pizza      Coke         Pizza        Milk
Dan        Taco       Coke         Steak        Water
```